# Can a narrative citation "Jones and colleagues (2019)..." be compliant with APA 7th standards?

Tags: citations, apa

I have been looking high and low and cannot find the answer to this question. I would prefer to replace the traditional Latin (et al.) with common English (and colleagues) in a narrative citation.

I recently had an article reviewer comment on my writing, saying "Jones and colleagues (2019)..." must be written "Jones et al. (2019)..."

I have looked though the APA 7th guidelines (Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association - 7th Edition) and find no such rule. Nor do I find where my style of writing is supported. So, is anything allowed which is not specifically disallowed? Or is anything wrong which is not specifically allowed?

I see on the APA website writing that follows this style, but these details are not in the official guidelines document.

- https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/02/et-al-when-and-how.html
- [https://www.apa.org/monitor/2019/02/legacy-trauma](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/02/et-al-when-and-how.html)

However, looking in Chapter 8 of the aforementioned guidelines does not make it clear. The narrative examples are only for a single author.

I would appreciate any authoritative help on this.

Comment: "I would prefer to replace the traditional Latin (et al.) with common English" - is there any particular reason you'd prefer to do this? For example, to make it easier to understand?

Comment: @F1Krazy Because I think English is difficult enough for those who learn it as a second language, and if I can remove the Latin bits, I believe it will be easier for those people to understand.

Comment: I suggest F1Krazy's query was more useful than the original Question.  What does English being difficult to learn as a second language have to do with 'Latin bits'?

Students are told this, that or the other is the way of things. How could it matter whether 'et al' came from Latin or from French, German or Greek, Sanskrit or Proto-Indo-European?

I see no possibility that cropping out Latin might make anything easier for second-language learners.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I do get your point. It is not that "et al." comes from Latin. It is that we have existing ways of saying the same thing without introducing words that only academics use. I, for one, would like to see English being more common and that means removing unnecessary complexities. Just like "indices" has become "indexes" because English is driven by common usage, I would argue that "et al." should become "and colleagues" for the same reason. Or, do we only want English to be used by the most sophisticated?

Comment: I suggest you're mistaken, and not only because I think 'et al' doesn't at all mean 'and colleagues' but rather 'and others' . To me, 'We have existing ways of saying the same thing without introducing (anything)…' insists such ways existed before 'et al', etc, came in. Do you believe that? I suggest 'et al' and even 'etc' are far from being words that only academics use, and that 'indices' becoming 'indexes' is not comparable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ben for the answer which gave me a very clear place to look in the APA 7th manual. It seems the rules are a little different in the 7th.

> **6.29 Latin Abbreviations**
>
> Use the following standard Latin abbreviations only in parenthetical material; in the narrative, use the translation of the Latin term. In both cases, punctuate as if the abbreviation were spelled out in the language in which you are writing.

This makes it look as though the rules are the same as what Ben wrote about the 6th edition. However, a little lower we see this in the 7th.

> Use the Latin abbreviation “et al.” (which means “and others”) in both
> narrative and parenthetical citations (see Section 8.17).

also, in section 8.17 it says this:

> For a work with three or more authors, include the name of only the first
> author plus “et al.” in every citation, including the first citation, unless
> doing so would create ambiguity

So, as it turns out, "et al." should not be translated in narrative citations because it is an exception.

Comment: Good that you found this! But it seems that while the rule has been phrased differently, its message remains the same: use *et al.* everywhere and do not translate it as "and colleagues".

Answer (score 1):

In the sixth edition of the APA Manual (p. 108) there is a clear rule for this:

> **4.26 Latin Abbreviations**
>
> Use the following standard Latin abbreviations only in parenthetical material; in non-parenthetical material, use the English translation of the Latin terms; in both cases, include the correct punctuation that accompanies the term:
>
> cf.   compare
> e.g.,   for example,
> , etc.   , and so forth
> i.e.,   that is,
> viz.,   namely,
> vs.   versus, against
>
> ...
>
> *Exception:* In the reference list and in text, use the Latin abbreviation *et al.*, which means *and others*, in nonparenthetical as well as parenthetical material.

The section heading, "Latin Abbreviations", is both in the table of contents and in the index of the sixth edition. Look for it in the seventh. But I would be surprised if this has changed.

---

You can of course always use English when you want to give background information about an author and their research:

> Marco Jones and his team from the University of Belfast have been studying Stack Exchange questions for the past thirty years and have developed the standard methodology. They have recently published a comprehensive summary of their findings (Jones et al., 2023).

But don't do this when you are just citing a source and the reader doesn't need to know more about who the authors are.

Comment: Thank you Ben. It was only because of your answer that I actually found the right place in the 282 page manual with the answer for the 7th edition (which I posted as a separate answer).